# Sed remove only first occurence of a string

Tags: regex, linux, shell, unix, sed

I have several string in my text file witch have this case:

```
 Brisbane, Queensland, Australia|BNE
```

I know how to use the SED command, to replace any character by another one. This time I want to replace the characters coma-space by a pipe, only for the first match to not affect the country name at the same time.

I need to convert it to something like that:

```
 Brisbane|Queensland, Australia|BNE
```

As you can see, only the first coma-space was replaced, not the second one and I keep the country name "Queensland, Australia" complete. Can someone help me to achieve this, thanks.

Here is a sample of my file:

```
 Brisbane, Queensland, Australia|BNE
 Bristol, United Kingdom|BRS
 Bristol, VA|TRI
 Brive-La-Gaillarde, France - Laroche|BVE
 Brno, Czech Republic - Bus service|ZDN
 Brno, Czech Republic - Turany|BRQ
```

If you do: sed 's/, /|/' file.txt doesn't work.

The output should be like that:

```
  Brisbane|Queensland, Australia|BNE
```

Comment: Unless you use the `g` modifier, substitutions only replace the first match on the line. So that's the default behavior, what's the problem you're having?

Comment: The problem is that I want for each line to replace the only first match of coma-space characters, not the second one to keep the full country name like that: Brisbane|Queensland, Australia|BNE. As there's twice coma-space for each line.

Comment: Please also post the expected output

Comment: Does it mean you want only the first line of the file?

Comment: No I said for each line, please read properly all the comments.

Comment: So what is wrong with my command? It does excatly what you want - it replace the first occurrence of a comma follow by a widespace by a | .. What means `not working` for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply don't use the `g` option. Your `sed` command should look like this:

```
sed 's/, /|/'
```

The `s` command will by default only the replace the first occurrence of a string in the pattern buffer - unless you pass the `g` option.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work, it's not a simple coma. It's a coma followed by a space.

Comment: have no clue, the topic looks clear but people still down voting it.

Comment: Works perfectly, forget to add the output redirection to see the result, Thank you very much!

Comment: you are welcome. please don't try to redirect to the original file (you would end up with and empty file.) If you want to modify the original file use the `-i` option instead)

Comment: I have not down voted you, but topic is not clear, since OP has not post other than the first line in his output, and there may be other way to interpreter what he means.

Comment: @Jotne Check the edit history of the question, there was demo data (I requested that), however OP rolled that back (for whatever reason) *sigh* :) ...

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not posted the output of your test file, we can only guess what you need.  And here is may guess:

```
awk -F", *" 'NF>2{$0=$1"|"$2 OFS $3}1' OFS=", " file
 Brisbane|Queensland, Australia|BNE
 Bristol, United Kingdom|BRS
 Bristol, VA|TRI
 Brive-La-Gaillarde, France - Laroche|BVE
 Brno, Czech Republic - Bus service|ZDN
 Brno, Czech Republic - Turany|BRQ
```

As you see it counts fields to see if it needs  `|` or not. If it neds `|` then  reconstruct the line.

Comment: I just get up, probably I just can't see it. Why you use the `$1=$1` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl not needed, removed :)